# how do I keep playing audio file in browser

Tags: javascript, audio, audio-streaming, web-audio-api

I am trying to play audio clips of audio receieved from server through socketio. The code works but on the first audio clip recieved is played, any clip recieved afterwards are not played. I confirmed their reciept but I don't know why it only plays the first received audio file.

```
   socketio.on('audio_playback_results', function (data) {
        console.log("I recieved an audio playback! ",data);
        playOutput(data);
    });


    function playOutput(arrayBuffer){
        let audioContext = new AudioContext();
        let outputSource;
        try {
            if(arrayBuffer.byteLength > 0){
                console.log(arrayBuffer.byteLength);
                audioContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer,
                function(buffer){
                    audioContext.resume();
                    outputSource = audioContext.createBufferSource();
                    outputSource.connect(audioContext.destination);
                    outputSource.buffer = buffer;
                    outputSource.start(0);
                },
                function(){
                    console.log(`playoutput PLAYING OUTPUT ARGUMMENT ${arguments}`);

                    // console.log(arguments);
                });
            }
        } catch(e) {

            console.log(`ERORRR PLAYING OUTPUT ${e}`);
        }
    }
```

i perform a text to audiobuffer on server side and then stream it back to client side.

```
async function textToAudioBuffer(text) {

  requestTTS.input = { text: text }; // text or SSML
    const response = await ttsClient.synthesizeSpeech(requestTTS);
    console.log("RESPONSE @ ttsClient, textToAudioBuffer() : ", response[0].audioContent)

    var results = response[0].audioContent

     io.emit('audio_playback_results', results);


  return response[0].audioContent;
}
```

what is causing it not to play audio clip recieved after the first one and how can I fix this ?

Comment: What format is your audio in?  And, why are you using Socket.IO for this?  You can usually just stream over HTTP and use an audio element.  If you must use Socket.IO, look into MediaSource Extensions, but it's more complicated *and* more limited.

Comment: @Brad i convert a text to audiobuffer using google TextToSpeech and then stream it back to client. How could I "just stream over HTTP and use an audio element" ?

Comment: Rather than using Socket.IO, you could just write your data as an HTTP response.  The client will stream this data.  If you already have the audio buffer though, why does it need to go to the server first and back to the client?

Comment: @Brad I am building a translation algorithm. the translation happens in the server and only the final result is sent back to client to be played.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Well yes, in any case, on HTTP request you can send that data directly over the response stream to the client, rather than working about Socket.IO.  Then client-side, you just need an `<audio>` tag.